# Google Cloud Auth

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to connect an automated build.  In the app I connect to a google api and in Cloud Run I access secrets both using different service accounts.  It's just a test app so nothing major but I keep getting hung up with cloud build using the service account that I use to access the api to run the app.  Anybody know of a way to dictate which service account is used to run the app while still using the key to access the api.  My thinking is it has to be done in the build process with something in my cloudbuild.yaml or maybe can't be done?

Comment: Can you share any documentation that you follow and can you provide any reproducible code?

Comment: Let me rephrase: You have a Cloud Build which has to access to different secret. Those secrets can be accessed by different service accounts. And  you want to access them from your Cloud Build, but your problem is that you can only use one service account in Cloud Build, correct?

Answer (score 0):

The cloud build process is carried out by a special service account that handles everything.  You can delegate the auth to other accounts but there really isn't any need.  Running the container in cloud run and choosing a service account to access secrets is easy (from Cloud Run choose edit and deploy => security tab) and that service account has no bearing on how you access other api's with creds.json you add at runtime.